# PyQt5 и способ получения в переменную пути к файлу

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, python-3.6, pyqt

Хочу просто и легко запускать в `PyQt5` диалоговое окно выбора файла типа такого (старый метод работает идеально кстати):

```
from tkinter import filedialog
wb_patch = filedialog.askopenfilename()
```

А вот такой код PyQt5:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
wb_patch = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
```

падает с 3 неизвестными ошибками в консоль.
Он вообще должен работать?

Comment: Эти ошибки неплохо было бы прикрепить к вопросу. И они должны говорить о том, что перед вызовом диалога необходимо создать `QApplication`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А так?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

wb_patch = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()[0]
print(wb_patch)

# Не обязательно нужен чтобы только путь получить,
# но при создании виджетов станет обязательным
# app.exec()
```

Comment: Заработало! спс! А что это за обязательный объект app? если он дальше не упоминается в присваивании переменной

Comment: @Углугбек, это объект `QApplication` -- важная и часто необходимая часть для виджетов Qt -- его нужно создавать до любых виджетов. Кст, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)